# Pandas, fillna/bfill to concat and coalesce fields

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do the following logic in a join_key. 
`date + book + bdr + COALECSE(cusip,isin,deal,id)`

```
+------------+------+------+-----------+--------------+------+------------+----------------------------+
|  endOfDay  | book | bdr  |   cusip   |     isin     | Deal |     Id     |          join_key          |
+------------+------+------+-----------+--------------+------+------------+----------------------------+
| 31/10/2019 |   15 | ITOR | 371494AM7 | US371494AM77 |  161 | 8013210731 | 20191031|15|ITOR|371494AM7 |
| 31/10/2019 |   15 | ITOR |           |              |      | 8011898573 | 20191031|15|ITOR|          |
| 31/10/2019 |   15 | ITOR |           |              |      | 8011898742 | 20191031|15|ITOR|          |
| 31/10/2019 |   15 | ITOR |           |              |      | 8011899418 | 20191031|15|ITOR|          |
+------------+------+------+-----------+--------------+------+------------+----------------------------+
```

I am trying to use :

```
df['join_key'] = ("20191031|" + df['book'].astype('str') + "|" + df['bdr'] + "|" + df[['cusip', 'isin', 'Deal', 'Id']].bfill(1)['cusip'].astype(str))
```

Also tried:

```
df['position_join_key'] = "20191031|" + df['book'].astype('str') + "|" + df['bdr'] + "|" + df['cusip'].fillna(df['isin']).fillna(df['Deal']).fillna(df['Id']).astype('str')
```

For some reason this code isnt picking up `Id` as part of the key.

For example in the 2nd row I should get `20191031|15|ITOR|8011898573`.

Also if it helps it comes from a csv where I use `na_filter = False`

**Sample Input:**

```
+------------+------+------+-----------+-------------+------+------------+
|  endOfDay  | book | bdr  |   cusip   |    isin     | Deal |     Id     |
+------------+------+------+-----------+-------------+------+------------+
| 31/10/2019 |   15 | ITOR | 371494AM7 |             |  161 | 8013210731 |
| 31/10/2019 |   15 | ITOR |           | 3.16248E+11 |      | 8011898573 |
| 31/10/2019 |   15 | ITOR |           |             |  352 | 8011898742 |
| 31/10/2019 |   15 | ITOR |           |             |      | 8011899418 |
+------------+------+------+-----------+-------------+------+------------+
```

**Sample output:**

```
+----------------------------+
|          join_key          |
+----------------------------+
| 43769|15|ITOR|371494AM7    |
| 43769|15|ITOR|316247735264 |
| 43769|15|ITOR|352          |
| 43769|15|ITOR|8011899418   |
+----------------------------+
```

Comment: there's a slight typo in your first piece of code, it should be `Id` not `id` assuming that might be the error in your script?

Comment: sorry that was my fault, My script is fine, I typod on the question. I still need help on this.

Comment: Are the empty cells in `cusip, isin, Deal` empty strings or `NaN`?

Comment: @Erfan, I believe empty strings, as when I import my csv I use `na_filter` I believe this gets rid of all `NaN`'s if im not mistaken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can approach your problem in a general way the following:

1. First we create a temporary column called `temp` which is the values backfilled.
2. We insert the column after your `bdr` column
3. We convert your date column to `datetime`
4. We can `'|'.join` the first 4 columns and create `join_key`

*notice*: step 3 I added to keep your code general, so we don't hardcode `20191031` like you did yourself.

```
s = df[['cusip', 'isin', 'Deal', 'Id']].replace('', np.NaN).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
df.insert(3, 'temp', s)

df['endOfDay'] = pd.to_datetime(df['endOfDay']).dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')

df['join_key'] = df.iloc[:, :4].apply(lambda x: '|'.join(x.astype(str).to_numpy()), axis=1)
df = df.drop(columns='temp')
```

```
   endOfDay  book   bdr      cusip          isin Deal          Id                     join_key
0  20191031    15  ITOR  371494AM7  US371494AM77  161  8013210731   20191031|15|ITOR|371494AM7
1  20191031    15  ITOR                                8011898573  20191031|15|ITOR|8011898573
2  20191031    15  ITOR                                8011898742  20191031|15|ITOR|8011898742
3  20191031    15  ITOR                                8011899418  20191031|15|ITOR|8011899418
```

Comment: thank you Erfan, couple questions, 1) I didnt use your 2nd step, as earlier in the code i input the date. So how does `df['join_key']` still pick this up?  2) What if I want to add a column what do i do?  3) What do I do if i want to add a `.` after `Id` and then add a column ?  ie `20191031|15|ITOR|8011898573.newcol`

Comment: It is quite unclear what is going wrong, I don't think the problem is very hard to solve, it's that your description is unclear. It is the easiest to just provide an example input dataframe and an example output dataframe. This way we can visually see what you want to do.

Comment: Please provide an input dataframe, so that when I run my solution, it will give a different output than your expected output you will provide

Comment: Where is `43769` in your `join_key` coming from?

Comment: Sorry that is endOfDay, just went copying to excel the format was off

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203037/discussion-between-erfan-and-excelguy).